# Oracle "Always Free-eligible" compute instance does not free becouse the Boot volume is paid

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am creating Oracle "Always Free-eligible" compute instance. I can selec"Always Free-eligible" for "Image and shape" option (1). But the Summury tooltip shows that I have to pay for the Boot volume (2).
[image]
How to select this Boot Volume at "Always Free-eligible" condition?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a product support / pricing question

Comment: This question is for Oracle, not Stack Overflow (it's not a programming question, and pricing is something you need to discuss with Oracle)

Comment: @david-makogon
- 1) The presence of infrastructure is an essential prerequisite for programming.
- 2) Free, long-term servers often present a unique opportunity to develop software products.
- 3) In forums in my native language, topics related to acquiring a server for programming are highly popular.
- 4) Just because you may not personally find infrastructure topics engaging doesn't mean other members share the same disinterest.
- 5) It's worth noting that Oracle does not offer support for the "Always Free-eligible" plan.

Comment: A lot of things are essential for programming, but that doesn't mean the questions are for Stack Overflow. This is specifically an Oracle support question. See [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) for clarification. This isn't any company's official support channel and it's off-topic here.

Comment: also, just to clarify on point 4: this isn't related in any way to my opinion of infrastructure topics, or my disinterest - it is specifically based on this site's guidelines. If you feel like your question is being improperly moderated, feel free to post on [meta] to discuss further.